# How in PostgreSql to join two tables and update the other table column based on specific cases from the join

Tags: database, postgresql

UPDATE

I updated the fiddle with an UPDATE which works somehow but still not the right result I need but cannot find a good way to solve it

The new fiddle
[New DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BUW9sb7x)

The issue I don't how can I get the last `statuses.type` on last valid timestamp before or equal the `comments.created_at`

I created the following fiddle to understand the data but I don't have an exmaple as I don't know how to resolve my issue

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MyceUWAz)

I have 2 tables `comments` and `statuses` and I need to join them where there is a candidate_id match. Canidates are not unique in both tables we can have same candidate multiple times.
Unique is the `statuses.type` a candidate cannot have same `status.type` twice.

Then I have to update the `comment` table the column `stage` based on the folowing case

The value of the comment stage column can be `AT_CALLCENTER` or `AT_SITE` and should be calculated in that way joining the 2 tables the `statuses.type` determine the stage value and follows the rule

```
AT_SITE: [
    'PENDING_SITE',
    'CONSENTED',
    'RANDOMIZED',
    'REJECTED_SITE',
    'REJECTED_CONSENTED',
    'REJECTED_RANDOMIZED',
  ],

  AT_CALLCENTER: ['PENDING_CALLCENTER', 'REJECTED_CALLCENTER'],
```

To determine in which `statuse.type` the comment was written we need to join last `statuses.type` valid at `comment.created_at` and `statuses.timestamps` the last type beore the comment was created show us at which stage was written based on those rules above

An example of the result based on the 2 tables from the fiddle we should have as follow

| id | candidate_id | user_id | content | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at | stage |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 329 | 0 | Hello comment!!! | 2019-04-16 08:24:14.916743+01 | 2019-04-16 08:25:33.635+01 | 2019-04-16 08:25:33.635+01 | AT_CALLCENTER |  |  |
| 2 | 324 | 0 | test | 2019-04-16 13:41:09.846586+01 | 2019-04-16 13:41:09.846586+01 | null | AT_SITE |  |  |
| 3 | 82 | 56 | This is a comment | 2019-04-17 12:49:48.526793+01 | 2019-04-17 12:49:48.526793+01 | null | AT_SITE |  |  |
| 4 | 324 | 0 | Cool! | 2019-04-24 09:39:20.233621+01 | 2019-04-24 09:39:20.233621+01 | null | AT_SITE |  |  |
| 214 | 11-0029 | 0 | i tried the candidate | 2019-06-24 15:15:23.775236+01 | 2019-06-24 15:15:23.775236+01 | null | AT_CALLCENTER |  |  |

The table rapresent the result expected after we updated the stage column by joing the 2 tables together

I didn't try any example as I don't know how to solve the problem and I'm expecting to see a result as showed from the example table, where the stage column is populated with the right value

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find my own solution and maybe that can help some other people having a particular issue as mine

```sql
UPDATE comments com
SET stage = CASE 
        WHEN sub.type IN (
                'PENDING_CALLCENTER',
                'REJECTED_CALLCENTER'
                )
            THEN 'AT_CALLCENTER'
        ELSE 'AT_SITE'
        END
FROM (
    SELECT c.id,
        c.candidate_id,
        c.created_at,
        s.type,
        s.TIMESTAMP,
        row_number() over (partition by c.id order by s.timestamp desc) as rn
    FROM comments c
    JOIN statuses s ON c.candidate_id = s.candidate_id
    WHERE c.created_at >= s.TIMESTAMP
    ) sub
WHERE sub.id = com.id
and sub.rn = 1;
```